# Bootstrap сетка не работает в тэге form

Tags: php, bootstrap, mysqli

Проблема: нужно сделать каталог товаров ввиде таблицы (как на 1 картинке), но тэги `<form>` не позволяют этого сделать - если их оставить, то получается как на второй картинке. Как решить эту проблему?

Как должно быть (1 картинка):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как есть (2 картинка): 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
<form name="form1" action="" method="post">
            <?php
            $link=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "products");
            mysqli_select_db($link,"checkbox");
            $result=mysqli_query($link,"select * from goods");
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) //Если бд не пустая, то выводится массив
            {
            ?> 
            <?php echo "<div class=\"col-sm-3\">" ?>  
            <?php echo "" ?>
            <?php echo "<div class=\"product-blocks\">" ?>    
                <input type="checkbox" name="num[]" class="other" value="<?php 
                echo $row["sku"]; 
                ?>" />
            <?php
            echo "<br>";
            echo $row["sku"] . "<br>";
            echo $row["name"] . "<br>";
            echo $row["price"] . "<br>";
            echo $row["size"] . "<br>";
            echo "</div>";    
            echo "</div>";    
            }
            ?>
            <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="delete selected">
            </form>
```

Comment: Если хотите, чтобы вам помогли, делайте пример кода ВОСПРОИЗВОДИМЫМ, посмотрите как сделать [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

У вас тут `Bootstrap`-ом даже не пахнет. -.-

---

[Bootstrap - Grid System](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style type="text/css">
      .css-block {
        padding: 50px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        margin: 10px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3 text-center"><div class="css-block">1</div></div>
        <div class="col-3 text-center"><div class="css-block">2</div></div>
        <div class="col-3 text-center"><div class="css-block">3</div></div>
        <div class="col-3 text-center"><div class="css-block">4</div></div>
        <div class="col-3 text-center"><div class="css-block">5</div></div>
        <div class="col-3 text-center"><div class="css-block">6</div></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Чем вам `<div class="col-sm-3">` и закрывающий `</div>` не bootstrap? Да и всё обернуто в row и container, просто вырезал проблемную часть кода.

Comment: @АндрейМельников как скажете...

Comment: Вам помогли, сделали за вас ваш пример воспроизводимым. Пометьте вопрос, как ответ, вместо возмущений. С "просто вырезанной" не воспроизводимой проблемной частью кода мало кто захочет возиться.